# Insert multidimensional associative array into multidimensional associative PHP

Tags: php

Hi all I have the following (this is an example of what I am attempting what I actually have is allot larger):

```
$array= array();
array_push($array,$var['bookshopname']);
$array[$var['bookshopname']]=array('opentime'=>$var1,'closetime'=>$var2);

foreach($array as $var)
{
print_r($var);
}
```

I get:

```
Storename1
Array ( [opentime] => 12 [closetime] => 17 ) 
Storename2
Array ( [opentime] => 13 [closetime] => 19 )
```

So if I count the array there are 4 elements
If I attempted the following

```
foreach($array as $var)
{
print_r($var['opentime']);
}
```

It breaks on the first result (Storename1).

I want the following

```
 array(
       Storename1 => array(opentime => ...)
       Storename2 => array(opentime => ...)
      )
```

and I am getting this:

```
 array(
       [0] => Storename1[Storename1] => Array ( [opentime ] =>....
       [1] => Storename2[Storename2] => Array ( [opentime ] =>....
      )
```

I cant quite figure out why it creates these two extra results with the names

In response to Oriol

When I try to update it further down the line

for example:

```
$array[$var['bookshopname']] = 
      array('opentime'=>$array[$var['bookshopname']]['opentime']+1,
            'closetime'=>$array[$var['bookshopname']]['closetime']-2);
```

Then it does not update the values but rather just replaces with the values I am trying to add or subtract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
$array= array();
$array[$var['bookshopname']]=array('opentime'=>$var1,'closetime'=>$var2);
```

Your code creates extra entries because of

```
array_push($array,$var['bookshopname']);
```

Maybe you should read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php to understand better what `array_push` does

**Edit**:

If you just want to modify the values, try this

```
$array[$var['bookshopname']]['opentime'] += 1;
$array[$var['bookshopname']]['closetime'] -= 2;
```

Comment: Ok 2 seconds going to implement and test

Comment: Its still not updating, but it appears that if (in_array($var['bookshopname'], $array)) is now never registering to true. Do you have any advise on this?

Comment: changing it to:   if (isset($array[$var['bookshopname']])) works like a charm. thank you for all your help :D

Comment: @David Yes, `in_array` searches array values, but in this case `$var['bookshopname']` is a key, so you need `isset` or `empty`